# D.Va's ejection - HUD problems

Tags: overwatch

I have been playing D.Va for a few hours now and I have encountered multiple times an oddity related to the ejection.

When my mech gets destroyed, D.Va gets out of the mech. Prior to the destruction, low mech health is symbolized by the HUD displaying sci-fi like warnings (what you'd expect from a mech).

However, once I am merely cannon fodder, my HUD sometimes re-enacts the behaviour of the mech described above (warnings and then a short black-screen similar to the one experienced during ejection).

This bug is not game-breaking in any way but it can be rather handicapping, especially during ranked matches.

---

Is this issue common ? My friends don't seem to encounter it.

If so, is there something I can do to avoid it ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

---

*Side-note : I have tried replicating the problem but couldn't. It seems to happen often (yet not always) after Roadhog's grab.*

Comment: [Is this your bug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JbJY-X1y4g)? Apparently its been around since the beta...

Comment: It is indeed the problem I experience. However, my bugged HUD lasts until I die or until I call a new mech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that happens when the mech is damaged by a melee attack while it's being destroyed. There is no way to prevent it as D.Va.

Comment: Thanks. I hoped this was an isolated bug that could be easily fixed. I just gotta avoid losing my mech.